# How to accumulate rows starting with a negative value until the result it positive?

Tags: postgresql

Let's pretend we have a table of weekly bank payments as shown below.

```
Week | Incoming | Outgoing | Outstanding (incoming + outgoing)   
 ----|----------|--------  |-------------
  1  | 100      |   -50    |    0                  
  2  | 500      |   -10    |    0                  
  3  | 600      |   0      |    0                 
  4  | 0        |   -100   |   -100              
  5  | 25       |   0      |    0                
  6  | 50       |   -10    |    0                 
  7  | 50       |   0      |    0
```

I want to add a new column that adds the previous outstanding amount until the total is positive as shown below.

```
Week | Incoming | Outgoing | Outstanding | Cummulative Outstanding 
 ----|----------|--------  |-------------|------------------------
  1  | 100      |   -50    |    0        |          0
  2  | 500      |   -10    |    0        |          0
  3  | 600      |   0      |    0        |          0
  4  | 0        |   -100   |   -100      |         -100
  5  | 25       |   0      |    0        |         -75
  6  | 50       |   -10    |    0        |         -35
  7  | 50       |   0      |    0        |          0
```

How can I use the result of a previous row for the next row?

Is it possible in Postgresql?

Comment: See [Lag Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-window.html)